# Cannot add/configure the kotlin frontend processResources conflict

Tags: javascript, gradle, kotlin, frontend

Im using kotlin with gradle to build a javascript front end and am getting the following exception:

An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.frontend', artifact: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-frontend-plugin:0.0.45']

> Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.gradle.java']
>   Cannot add task 'processResources' as a task with that name already exists.

here is my gradle.build.kts:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

plugins{
    kotlin("js")
    kotlin("frontend")
    id("kotlin-dce-js")
}

tasks.compileKotlinJs {
    kotlinOptions.metaInfo = true
    kotlinOptions.outputFile = "$project.buildDir.path/js/${project.name}.js"
    kotlinOptions.sourceMap = true
    kotlinOptions.moduleKind = "umd"
    kotlinOptions.main = "call"
}

kotlinFrontend {
    npm {
        dependency ("style-loader") // production dependency
        devDependency ("karma")     // development dependency
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated